# How to set 2 network addapters using virtualbox?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, netplan

I have installed a VBOX virtual machine with Ubuntu 18.04.03 LTS in which I want to use 2 network connections, a NAT and a Bridge ones.

Show when I enable this adapters and start Ubuntu virtual machine, I try to see all the network cards I have, using:

```
lshw -c network -businfo
```

With that, i see that I have 2 devices, enp0s3 and enp0s8, but when I use the ifconfig, only the enp0s3 is shown.

How can I enable the enp0s8? I have tried adding to

```
netplan 50-cloud-init.yml
```

and executing `sudo netplan apply`

But nothing changes for me

Thanks!

Comment: > netplan 50-cloud-init.yml 
Is this a typo?  Note that the file that is precreated on the system is called /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml, and that netplan only recognizes files with a .yaml extension, not .yml.

Comment: In order for us to help you, please post the complete contents of the netplan configuration you're attempting to use, as well as the output of running `sudo netplan --debug apply`.